# Binary Powershell Modules - get the value of a global variable from the Powershell host

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

How do I get the value of a global variable, such as `$ConfirmPreference` from the Powershell host from within a binary Powershell module written in C#?

Comment: Global variables are specific for `Runspace`, while same `PSHost` can have multiple `Runspace`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PSCmdlet.GetVariableValue(string)` method can be used for this:

```
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace MyModule
{

    [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "GetVariableValueMethod")]
    public class TestGetVariableValueMethod : PSCmdlet
    {
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            ConfirmImpact confirmPref =
                (ConfirmImpact)this.GetVariableValue("global:ConfirmPreference");
            WriteObject(confirmPref);
        }
    }
}
```

Testing within Powershell:

```
PS > Test-GetVariableValueMethod
High

PS > $ConfirmPreference = 'Low'

PS > Test-GetVariableValueMethod
Low
```